# Oracle Case in WHERE Clause with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

I'm trying to pass a case statement in my where clause but it seems I'm missing something or it's not possible in my scenario below is my code

explanation of the code "if the sysdate is Sunday I want to retrieve data for the past 3 days else take yesterday data"

```
    FROM lea_nf1.lea_agreement_dtl c--, lea_nf1.LEA_GUARANTOR_HIRER_DTL d
   WHERE
            case when to_char(sysdate,'Day') = 'Sunday' then 
            to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm')
            and to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy')
            and C.DISBURSALDATE between trunc(sysdate-3) and trunc(sysdate-1)
            else 
            to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm')
            and (to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy')
            and C.DISBURSALDATE < sysdate end
ORDER BY C.DISBURSALDATE desc
```

below is the error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Skip the case _expression_, use regular AND/OR instead.

Comment: Oracle have no boolean datatype, that's why you cannot evaluate `case` expression to the result of some predicate

Comment: Are you sure your logic is correct (even disregarding the code)? If it's Sunday you want to go three days back, if not only one day back. Since it's **three** vs one (not **two** vs one), does that mean that Saturday is special too? And if so, shouldn't you also have different conditions for a Saturday, not only for a Sunday? If you tell us the actual task (rather than just code), we may help you find much simpler, more elegant and more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, you can't use a `case` statement to build a `where` clause like this. What you could do, however, is use logical operators to get the desired behavior:

```
WHERE
    (to_char(sysdate,'Day') = 'Sunday' AND 
     to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm') AND
     to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy') AND
     C.DISBURSALDATE between trunc(sysdate-3) and trunc(sysdate-1)) OR
    (to_char(sysdate,'Day') != 'Sunday' AND
     to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm') AND
     to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy') AND
     C.DISBURSALDATE < sysdate)
```

This can of course be simplified by extracting the common conditions on both sides of the `or` operator:

```
WHERE
    to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm') AND
    to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy') AND
    (to_char(sysdate,'Day') = 'Sunday' AND 
     C.DISBURSALDATE between trunc(sysdate-3) and trunc(sysdate-1)) OR
    (to_char(sysdate,'Day') != 'Sunday'  AND
     C.DISBURSALDATE < sysdate)
```

Or, if you take it a step further, any `C.DISBURSALDATE` that is `between trunc(sysdate-3) and trunc(sysdate-1)` is also always `< sysdate`, so:

```
WHERE
    to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm') AND
    to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy') AND
    C.DISBURSALDATE < sysdate AND
    (to_char(sysdate,'Day') != 'Sunday' OR
     C.DISBURSALDATE between trunc(sysdate-3) and trunc(sysdate-1))
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but none of them worked i tried to replace the Day from sunday to friday so i can test hte code it keeps showing the same result on both

Comment: @Sulzehq oops! Forgot to add `to_char(sysdate,'Day') != 'Sunday'` on the other side of the `or` operator... mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

The CASE statement returns a "column value" that cannot be evaluated as a WHERE CONDITION itsef, but you can use it as a value 1 or 3 depending on sysdate, and then use this value in the filter condition:

```
WHERE
TRUNC(C.DISBURSALDATE) >=
TRUNC(
    SYSDATE  - 
    (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'Day') = 'Sunday' THEN 3 ELSE 1 END) -- this case will return 3 or 1, and use it to subtract from sysdate
    )
AND TRUNC(C.DISBURSALDATE) < TRUNC(SYSDATE) --this is just because I am not sure if your data has dates after today
```

Also, you do not need the clauses below to filter the dates:

```
to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'mm') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'mm') AND
to_char(C.DISBURSALDATE , 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy')
```

Comment: thanks i had to slightly modify your code to make it work perfectly..